# Creating a View for combined feeds in Drupal

Tags: drupal, view, rss, aggregator

So I have subscribed to two outside feeds on Drupal as well as have made a few blogs and gotten the rss feed for the blog on my site as well. I have made all three of these feeds fall under a category. Now, I want to make a View that shows the title, author, and clipped text for 5 items in my combined feed.

I haven't been able to do this. I created a view and selected "show aggregator item" but can't figure out how to fill out the rest of the form so as to display the content in drupal/aggregator/categories/1

Comment: a link to an article walking me through it would be awesome too. i couldn't find one that did this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was on the right track, all I needed to do was specify the field items. The default settings just try displaying an ID that non of the articles had so I removed that and added Title, Author, body... and it works!